# load node_modules with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I want to load some modules, for instance:

- moment
- echarts

My package.json:

- "echarts": "^3.1.10"
- "moment": "^2.14.1"

but I have the next errors:

VM2282:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined(…)

My Webpack config:

`{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: /node_modules/
}`

I do not know what happend. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I think you haven't posted all the relevant code, have you?

Comment: Did you manually require('moment')? You should at least paste the code which is generating the error.

Comment: I have an angular 2 project and I wrote the require('moment') in the src/main.browser.ts. My project is the same as: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter because I am using this project as template. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to vendor.ts:

```
import 'echarts';
import 'moment';
```

and remove your code from webpack config.
This works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I can see in vendor.bundle.js the references to moment and echarts but I cannot access to the moment() method. For instance, I open the Chrome Console, I write moment() and I have the next error: VM350:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined(…).

Comment: Hey! Remove imports from vendor.ts! Add to your .ts file where you are writing code "import * as moment from 'moment'" and webpack will import moment library from node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import '../../public/css/styles.css';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent { 

  constructor(){
    let now = moment().format('LLLL');
    console.log(now)
  }
}
```